# Multiple threads writing to sequential array in cuda kernel

Tags: cuda

I am writing a cuda kernel which requires me to allocate an array of aligned `struct` on the device.
I am getting the correct results from my computations and I need to write the values to this array starting from index `0`.

When I try to write to this array and display the results back to host side, some of the answers are displayed as zero.

Clearly, I am not increasing the index as per my requirement. I tried using counter which I increase using `atomicAdd()`, however I still get some values as zero.

To be precise, I may use `1000` threads in my kernel for computations but my output allocated array can have a size less than `100` or more than `10000`.

My question is, how do I make all these threads write the value to exactly one location of array ( as they are calculated ) and increment the array index/counter by `1` without overwriting it.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code illustrating what the kernel does would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `atomicAdd()`. It returns the old value, so you use that value as the index:

```
old_i = atomicAdd(&i, 1);
out_array[old_i] = val
```

However, you will get poor performance if many of your threads write out results, as the atomicAdd() will (indirectly) serialize all the writes. In that case, you should let each thread write its result,if any, to a slot set aside for that thread and then use a compaction algorithm (see `thrust::copy_if`), to gather up the results.

Comment: Thanks...This solved my problem.I was using `atomicAdd()` after assigning the values to array.And yes,it is expensive for my computations. I am looking for other techniques that might speed my computations while utilizing the memory more efficiently.