# Is that possible to use the push_back method on kernel of CUDA?

Tags: cuda, thrust

In my code, I want to push_back my date on the `__global__ function`,and it is hard to use array here. So I want to know is that possible to use the push_back method on kernel of CUDA?
Can I use the `std::vector` on the `__global__` function through some other way,or how to use the `thrust::vector` on  `__global__` function.

Can somebody give me an example code?

Comment: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786495/cuda-kernel-returning-vectors/21788662#21788662) an example of something like push_back

Comment: Thank you very much and can you help me with my code? I still do not know how to do with it. May I have your email address?

Comment: You can find an appropriate answer in [here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534700/multiple-threads-writing-to-sequential-array-in-cuda-kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible either `std::vector` or `thrust::vector` in CUDA kernel code. Thrust is a host side abstraction for GPU arrays and algorithms which cannot be used inside CUDA kernels.

You should rethink approach. `push_back` style appending of data is an fundamentally serial operation which requires some sort of locking or atomic operation in data parallel execution models. This almost always has negative performance impact on GPU code.

Comment: I will appreciate if you can help me to review my code and find some way to solve my problem.May I have your email address and send my code to you?